# Is there a way to load a fragment from the back stack using the Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have a number of custom tabs, and I want the NavController to load a fragment from the back stack if it exists when the user navigates between tabs.

I check if a fragment exists in my back stack, and if it doesn't, I navigate to it. However, how can I load a fragment from the back stack when it already exists there?

```
try {  //check if fragment exists in back stack
    navController.getBackStackEntry(R.id.myFragment);

    // what should I do here?
} catch (Exception e) {
    navController.navigate(R.id.action_to_myFragment);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the fragment on the backstack, you can use the code below.

```
findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.myFragment, false)

// argument false : inclusivity settings
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It almost works, but it seems that when we use the 'popBackStack' method, it clears some of the fragments from the top of the stack to reach our destination. So, if I go back to those fragments using tabs, do I need to load them again?

Comment: If it is a non-existent fragment, it will need to be loaded. Don't forget to check using the inclusivity value.

Answer (score 1):

try popBackStack:

```
try {
  
    NavBackStackEntry entry = navController.getBackStackEntry(R.id.myFragment);

    if (entry != null) {
        // Pop fragments from the back stack 
        navController.popBackStack(entry.getDestination().getId(), false);
    } else {
      
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_to_myFragment);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle exceptions if necessary
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It almost works, but it seems that when we use the 'popBackStack' method, it clears some of the fragments from the top of the stack to reach our destination. So, if I go back to those fragments using tabs, do I need to load them again?